# Spring and Hibernate: Loading cfg.xml into application context

Tags: spring, hibernate

`datasource.hibernate.cfg.xml` has hiberanteProperties and all the mapping resources. 
But right now I have to define mapping resources and properties in `applicationContext.xml` separately.
Can I just specify datasource.hibernate.cfg.xml as `configLocation` inside `<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean">` and get rid of both `mappingResources and hibernateProperties`. Right now my application context looks like this:

```
<property name="mappingResources"/>
            <list>
                <value>../../src/editsolutions.hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
            </list>
        <property name="hibernateProperties"> 
           <props> 
           <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop> 
           <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">3</prop> 
           <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop> 
           <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"> 
               org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory 
           </prop> 
           <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"> 
              com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate.TransactionManagerLookup 
           </prop> 
           </props>
        </property>
```

Note: I don't use annotations for entity classes. It's a legacy project and everything is defined via `hbm.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set 'configLocation' property and get rid of other properties. [See](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setConfigLocation%28org.springframework.core.io.Resource%29)